# Problema para cargar archivo de mas de 30mb con php

Tags: php, upload

no puedo cargar archivos de mas de 30mb en mi servidor, en el navegador me marca el error **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**
y con el programa
Charles Web Debugging Proxy me aparece "**Failure: Socket: Software caused connection abort: socket write error**".
ya se modifico el archivo php.ini y se aumentaron los valores pero sigue sin funcionar.
cual creen que sea la causa o que falta configurar?
los archivos pequeños se cargan sin problema.

Este es el codigo que se usa para subir los archivos

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['uploadedFile'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'];

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"audios/".$file_name)){
  echo "Success";
 }
else{
echo "no se cargo archivo";
}

   }
?>
 
  <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "uploadedFile" />
     <input type = "submit"/>
       <?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
?>
     <ul>
        <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];  ?>
        <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size'];  ?>
        <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'] ?>
     </ul>
<?php }?>
       
  </form>
```

y estos son los valores de php.ini

- memory_limit=2048M
- upload_max_filesize=200M
- post_max_size=200M
- max_execution_time=10000
- display_errors=On
- error_reporting=E_ALL &    ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
- session.save_path="/tmp"
- magic_quotes_gpc=Off
- max_input_time=1000
- max_file_uploads=200
- allow_url_fopen=On
- ignore_user_abort=On
- max_input_vars=2000